# MySQL: extract the most frequent value for an element

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a DB table with a set of Texts and, for each of them, five (5) emotions. What I need to do is to get the most frequent emotion for each group of rows, only if that emotion appears at least three times. Otherwise, I do not want to show the aggregated row in the result set.
For instance I have:

```
text     | emotion
nice day | happyness
nice day | happyness
nice day | neutral
nice day | neutral
nice day | happyness
hello    | sadness
hello    | sadness
hello    | surprise
hello    | surprise
hello    | neutral
```

And the output should be:
nice day | happyness 
In that case, the text "Hello" is not displayed, since there are no emotions that occur at least 3 times.

I tried many solutions but I cannot find a working one...

Comment: what have you tried so far ? show your query which you tried

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, `HAVING`

Comment: For instance I tried: select text, emotion from table_name group by text but I cannot figure out how to filter texts that do not have at least three equal emotions

Comment: Note that your table has no PRIMARY KEY, which will prove problematic in due course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky:

```
select text, emoticon
from t
group by text, emoticon
having count(*) >= 3 and
       count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.text = t.text
                   group by t2.emoticon
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

Answer (score 1):

let's say your table name is emotions so the code will be

```
select text,emotion
from emotions
group by text,emotion
having count(emotion)>2
```

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns